# How can I setup a shared library between a bootloader and an application?

Tags: linker, bootloader, texas-instruments, code-composer, openthread

I am in the process of implementing over-the-air updates on a CC2652 microcontroller using the OpenThread stack.
As far as I know a bootloader has to be able to operate independently from the application and be as small as possible. But for the bootloader to download the new firmware by itself it will have to implement the OpenThread stack which will add quite a lot to its size.

I was wondering if it is possible to share the OpenThread stack between the two. 
I have heard it is possible to place the functions of the library in a specific place in memory and to then share the address with the application but I don't know how to do this in my IDE, Code Composer Studio, or how to make the IDE behave like the library was just a regular import when working on the application with things like auto completion etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look [here](http://software-dl.ti.com/simplelink/esd/simplelink_cc13x2_26x2_sdk/3.40.00.02/exports/docs/thread/html/thread-oad/native-oad.html), TI is working on OTA support.
Even if it has nothing to do with OpenThread itself..

The application itself will download the image and the bootloader just reflashes it.
so you have to take care that there is space for two FW-images in flash or using an external flash for this..

Hope it helps.. btw, here's a cool stick i found:
https://www.tindie.com/products/slaesh/cc2652-zigbee-coordinator-or-openthread-router/